# Summernote removes nested list and posts single list on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, summernote

```
<form name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="submit.php" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="overview">Overview</label>
          <textarea rows="3" id="overview" class="form-control" name="overview"></textarea>
        </div>
</form>
<script>
 $('#overview').summernote({height: 300});
function validateForm() {
  var xyz = document.forms["myForm"]["overview"];
  alert(xyz.value);
}
</script>
```

This is the code that is seen on clicking on source code option.

```
<ul><li>abc</li><li>das<ul><li>ads</li><li>df</li></ul></li></ul>
```

But on submit it becomes

```
<ul><li>abc</li><li>das</li><li>ads</li><li>df</li></ul>
```

If i manually change the code as follows:

```
<ul><li>abc</li><li>das</li><ul><li>ads</li><li>df</li></ul></ul>
```

Then I get the expected result.
Dont know whats the reason behind it.Please help?

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle for your issue or can you give more context ?

Comment: This is an invalid HTML! You can't nest `ul` directly under another `ul` element

Comment: @Prince: I am using summernote text editor in my php site.So i'm getting this issue when creating nested list else everything working fine.

Comment: @AlonEitan I know its not valid but for some reason its working otherwise editor removes inner <ul> tag.

Comment: The best practise is to always use a valid HTML, otherwise you'll get unexpected results, just use valid HTML structure

Comment: can you please more code, what have you written on submit button and other code related to this feature?

Comment: I'm using valid html but nested list gets removed on submit and the elements are shown in that original list.

Comment: I have alerted value in validation section on submit.There it removes the inner ul tag.

Comment: You should nest the inner `ul` inside a `li` element (`<ul><li>abc</li><li><ul><li>inner abc</li></ul></li></ul>`)

Comment: You can edit your question and insert more code there

Comment: @Prince: I have edited the code.

Comment: @kamalpreetkaur Please check my previous comment, I think this is what you're looking for, and it should work

Comment: @kamalpreetkaur Please check the suggestion by AloEitan. I think it will help you.

Comment: @Prince: this is what I'm talking about https://jsfiddle.net/x4sp8uy2/2/

Comment: create a nested list and click on 1st box below to get the current value of box

Comment: @AlonEitan Take a loot at the fiddle

Comment: Checked your jsfiddle and looks like an issue of summernote editor. Summernote editor always return wrong markup and seems like they have implemented in this way only, see this link - https://github.com/summernote/summernote/pull/2986. I think you cannot do much and should just pass it like if needed to send to backend.

Comment: Solved it just by substituting $('#summernote').summernote('code'); in textarea value before submit.